# Particularization in algebraic statements in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm new to Isabelle and I'm still becoming familiar with the basics.

I have an algebra for which `(x || y) ; (z || w) <= (y ; z) ; (x || w)` is an axiom,  `1` is a neutral element for both `;` and `||` (on both sides) and the `<=` relation is antisymmetric.

The  current goal is to prove `||` is commutative.

On a paper and pencil proof, one could note the statement holds for all `x`, `y`, `w` and `z`, and in particular for `w = 1` and `z = 1`, and simplify to show `(x || y) <= (y || x)`. Then one could note the same statement holds under a renaming of variables, obtaining `(y || x) <= (x || y)`, and conclude `(x || y) = (y || x)`, since `<=` is antisymmetric.

However, I'm not sure how that translates to the Isabelle setting!

Assuming `z = 1` and `w = 1` requires an additional hypothesis, which does not hold in general, and I did not find a way to express particularization.

As requested in the comments, here I include the current state of the lemma:

```
lemma par_is_commutative [simp] :
  " x || y = y || x "
proof -
  have exchange : " (x || y) ; (z || w) \<sqsubseteq> (y ; z) || (x ; w) " by (metis exchange_law)
  assume z_is_one : "z = 1"
  assume w_is_one : "w = 1"
  have replace_by_one :
    " (x || y) ; (1 || 1) \<sqsubseteq> (y ; 1) || (x ; 1) "
    by (metis exchange z_is_one w_is_one)
  have simplify_ones :
    " (x || y ) \<sqsubseteq> (y || x) "
    by (metis
          replace_by_one
          one_is_seq_neuter_right
          one_is_par_neuter_right)
  have swapped_exchange :
    " (y || x) ; (z || w) \<sqsubseteq> (x ; z) || (y ; w) "
    by (metis exchange_law)
  have swapped_replace_by_one : 
    " (y || x) ; (1 || 1) \<sqsubseteq> (x ; 1) || (y ; 1) "
    by (metis swapped_exchange z_is_one w_is_one)
  have swapped_simplify_ones :
    " (y || x ) \<sqsubseteq> (x || y) "
    by (metis
          swapped_replace_by_one
          one_is_seq_neuter_right
          one_is_par_neuter_right)
  have symmetric_order :
    "(y || x ) \<sqsubseteq> (x || y) \<and> (x || y ) \<sqsubseteq> (y || x) "
    by (metis
          swapped_simplify_ones
          simplify_ones)
  have commutativity :
    " (y || x) = (x || y) "
    sorry
    (* by (metis
        symmetric_order
        local.leq_is_antisymmetric
        
    *)
```

This does not work, since `x` and `y` are assumed to be `1`, and I can't even figure out where `leq_is_antisymmetric` is.

Comment: Hi! In order to obtain an appropriate answer, could you specify what you *can* write at this point about the statement in Isabelle?

Comment: Hola Pedro! Agregué el código con un edit para contestar a la pregunta literalmente, aunque no creo que agregue mucho. Contestando al énfasis en _can_, nada.

Comment: It turned out it was possible to replace `z` and `w` with 1s in `exchange` directly, so none of this was required! Perhaps in more involved cases particularization cannot be done directly, but here and in similar cases it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the above code block seems that you can not specialize statements by using `assume`.

`assume "z = 1"` will add that fact to your assumption list, but then you'll end up only with a proof of that particular case.

Instead, you should deduce the particular case from the general instance, as in the following example.

```
theory Scratch

imports Main

begin

notepad begin
  fix f g :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  assume hyp: "⋀x. f(x) = g(x)"
  from hyp
  have "f(1) = g(1)" .
end
```

Here, the particular case follows immediately from the general statement `hyp` by the "trivial" proof method (abbreviated by `.`). Actually, in a situation as simple as this one, you would write something like `hyp[of "1"]` to invoke the particular case.